# Find smallest $n$ such that $64p^3$ and $q^{11}$ divides $n^5$

Tags: number-theory

Find smallest $n$ such that $64p^3$ and $q^{11}$ divides $n^5$, where $p,q$ are prime.

I tried

$$a64p^3 = n^5\Longrightarrow 2(ap^3)^{1/5}\in\mathbb{Z}\Longrightarrow a=p^2$$

$$bq^{11} = n^5\Longrightarrow (bq^{11})^{1/5}\in \mathbb{Z}\Longrightarrow b=q^4$$

But this implies that

$$n=q^3 = 2p$$,

which seems to be impossible.

Comment: Utterly no reason to assume a is a fifth power.

Comment: a is not a fifth power.  a is the stuff left over to push everything else up to a fifth power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $p\ne 2; q\ne 2; p \ne q$ then

Let $a = \prod p_i^{n_i}$

we need $2|a$ and $q|a$ and $p|a$ but we need not assume anymore.  So to make $n$ minimal we can assume there are no other prime factors.

So $a = 2^kp^jq^l$

$2^6 =64|a^5 = 2^{5k}p^{5j}q^{5l}$ so $5k \ge 6$.  The least possible $k$ is $2$.

$p^3|2^{5k}p^{5j}q^{5l}$ so $5j \ge 3$. the least possible $j$ is $1$.

$q^{11}|2^{5k}p^{5j}q^{5l}$ so $5l \ge 11$.  the least possible $l$ is $3$.

So the least possible $n = 2^2pq^3=4pq^3$

So $64p^3|n^5 = 2^{10}p^5q^15 = (64p^3)16p^2q^15$ So $n^5 = a*(64p^3); a=16p^2q^15$

and $q^11|n^5 =2^{10}p^5q^15 = (q^{11})1024p^5q^4$. So $n^5 = b*q^{11}; b = 1024p^5q^4$

Notice in neither case is $a$ nor $b$ a 5th power.  $a$ and $b$ are just the "stuff left over" to *make* the product a 5th power.  It isn't a fifth power itself.  Indedd if it *were* a fifth power we'd be utterly @@@@ed.

Answer (score 2):

For ensuring minimality a necessary condition is that $n$ should be divisible by no primes other than $2,p,q$.

Now take $n=2^ap^bq^c$. So $n^5=2^{5a}p^{5b}q^{5c}$. For $64=2^6$ to divide this we need $6\leq 5a$. Similarly work out inequalities for $b.c$ and get the least positive integers  $a,b,c$ satisfying the inequalities.

Comment: Where did my argument go wrong?

Comment: There are  3 divisibility conditions. You should find the  least number satisfying ALL the three conditions. You are trying for each condition individually the least number satisfying it. In my office  X may be the youngest person earning more than me, and Y may be the youngest person taller than me. But the youngest person who is both taller than me and earns more may neither be X nor Y.